# How to print in pdf a multi page word document: one file per page

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, pdfcreator

I have a word document with 10 pages, is it possible to save/print in pdf one page per one file?

```
Page1 --> FilePdf1
Page2 --> FilePdf2
```

etc

Comment: well just select one page, not all pages, then print to the pdf file. Repeat for all 10 pages

Comment: Nooooo.... If the document will be 50 pages? ;-) I'm looking for an automated procedure.

Comment: I googled "print each page of a word file to pdf" (sans quotes) and found a number of suggestions.  This one includes a VBA macro to do the job:  https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/5420-word-save-each-page-as-separate-pdf.html

Answer (score 1):

Print document to PDF as usual, then use a Split PDF program such as this: https://www.pdf2go.com/split-pdf

Answer (score 0):

Would it meet your needs if you printed the entire document to a single pdf, then in acrobat used "Organize Pages" > [select all pages] > "Extract" > "Extract pages as separate files"?

This will result in a separate pdf file for each page with the number at the end of the file name.

[Acrobat Pro DC]

Answer (score -1):

You could try [Ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com/) from the command line, either entering multiple commands to GhostScript for each page, perhaps in a `.bat` file, or do a bit of VBScript or Python to loop through the pages. It might also be possible to write VBScript inside Word to do this, but that might take more time and experimentation.